# How can get all row from subgrid collapsed in Jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php, subgrid

I have made a grid thats working fine and subgrids with it. When subgrid expanded I can get all row from parent Grid and subgrid by:

```
$("#" + parentGrid).find('tr[role="row"]:not(.ui-jqgrid-labels, .jqgfirstrow, .ui-subgrid)').each(function () {
    // Get all row here
}
```

The problem is, When subGrid is collapsed, I can't find any row from it. Is there any way to get all row from subGrid has been closed? Is it possible?

Comment: Why no one answer? no one comment? I have 3 day to fix bug. hu hu

Comment: Could you include more information about what you do? How you create jqGrid and subgrids? Which `datatype` has both? Which options you use? Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? Don't expect that somebody solves your problems in short time, just try to formulate your problem better. By the way default options of subgrid means that subgrid will be **deleted** on collapsing and thus it can't be found.

Comment: By the way [the page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jqgrid-php/info) describes what means "jqgrid-php" tag. Is it the product, which you use?

Comment: Thanks all, i has been solved my problem: just set expandOnLoad: true, reloadOnExpand: false. table will not destroy when you collapsed